# Ошибка при скачивании rvm

Tags: ubuntu, curl

устанавливаю райлс по стандартному плану 
и на первом же шаге возникла ошибка 
прикладываю скрин:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как ее исправить?

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]! текстовую информацию лучше выкладывать не в виде изображения, а в виде текста. по сути вопроса: похоже на сбой либо на сайте github.com, либо где-то по пути к вашему компьютеру.

Comment: Поставьте перед командой `sudo`

Comment: @LEQADA, при ошибке записи на диск логичнее всего сначала проверить, есть ли на диске свободное место.

Comment: @MR_dONE, приложите, пожалуйста, к вопросу вывод программы `df`. изменить вопрос можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, это было бы логично 10 лет назад. Сегодня логичнее всего проверить права на запись )

Comment: @LEQADA *проверить права на запись* — в принципе, вы, скорее всего, правы. после «бессмысленного и беспощадного» использования программы sudo там, где надо и не надо, пожалуй, стоит время от времени проверять доступность записи в *собственный* домашний каталог.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, я посмотрел скрипт по ссылке между строк. Он вроде качает в какую-то другую директорию. Которая вне домашней. Хотя это слишком запутанно для меня. Не люблю разбираться в таких скриптах.

Comment: @LEQADA, я тоже внимательно посмотрел на этот скрипт. и после этого могу лишь сказать, что я не стал бы его запускать никогда и ни при каких обстоятельствах. очень надеюсь, что сама программа rvm написана более аккуратными программистами.

Comment: RVM это весьма уважаемая штука в Ruby-сообществе. Но никаких `sudo`! Ей это не нужно, она по умолчанию ставится в юзерспейс.

Answer (score 1):

По вашей ссылке находится скрипт файл, который что-то мутит. Как видно из того, что выводится на экран, скрипт пытается скачать файл, но выкидывает `curl status 23`.

Идём на [curl the man page](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer) и читаем, что этот статус означает. А означает он

> Write error. Curl couldn't write data to a local filesystem or
>   similar.
>
> Ошибка записи. Curl не может записать данные в файловую систему или
>   что-то в такое

Значит что-то не позволяет нам записать данные. Даём права

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable
```

Answer (score -1):

Добавьте sudo
используйте установщик с [официального сайта](https://rvm.io/)
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable

Comment: На скриншоте сделано именно это, но без `sudo`, так же, как на официальном сайте :)