# Как решить проблему с путями установки ruby, rvm на Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Случайно удалил Ruby, до этого он находился в каталоге /usr/bin/..., теперь пытаюсь поставить заново ruby и rails, нагуглил что по быстрому это можно сделать через rvm. Установил для начала rvm, который установился в /home/****/.rvm/bin/rvm, и когда устанавливаю ruby - она также ложится в этот каталог. Не знаю плохо ли это, но как по мне то да. Ибо sass, compass, gem - все в /usr/local/bin
При запуске на шторме приложения, где используется compass - gulp выдает ошибку: `events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn /usr/local/bin/compass ENOENT
Вопрос, как переместить ruby в /usr/local/bin или как установить ruby в этот каталог?

Comment: *когда устанавливаю ruby* — каким образом устанавливаете?

Comment: с помощью rvm: curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Это нормально.

RVM и все управляемые ею компоненты (интерпретаторы Ruby, гемы, обёртки) лежат в одной папке с ним. Установив Ruby из RVM, вы получаете отдельную Ruby-среду. Гемы в неё нужно установить отдельно, они тоже пойдут в `~/.rvm` и, что важно и удобно, они **никогда не будут требовать `sudo`** (*кроме как для установки нативных зависимостей в систему, конечно*).

Вам останется только прописать для "шторма" (что бы это ни было) одну запись в `PATH`, которая всплывёт, если вы посмотрите в своей шелл-сессии, какой её сделал RVM:

```
rvm use ruby
echo $PATH
```

Одна из папок, указанных там, должна будет вести туда, где RVM хранит "обёртки" исполняемых файлов от гемов. Вам нужно донести эту же папку в `PATH` до "шторма". **Всё.**

Answer (score 1):

если вам по каким-то причинам не подходит [пакет из репозитория](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/#apt), то [для общесистемной установки](https://rvm.io/rvm/install#1-download-and-run-the-rvm-installation-script) следует запустить [этот скрипт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/485713#comment564943_485713) от имени пользователя root:

```
$ curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable --ruby
```